# How to convert access database accdb to accde using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I use this code to open access database :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application AccApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
string MyFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Baseet.accdb";

AccApp.Visible = true;
AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(MyFile, false, "017014A");
AccApp.RunCommand(AcCommand.acCmdAppMaximize);
```

I need to :
1-Enable macro content for this database only (I don't want to add the location to Trusted locations .
2- convert the opened database to `accde` , I tried `AccApp.RunCommand(AcSysCmdAction.` but couldn't find convert to `accde` code which is 603 I guess .
Thanks

Edit #1 The database is protected with a password you can find it in my code , I tried this code :

```
string MyCompiledFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Baseet.accde";
AccApp.SysCmd (603 , MyFile , MyCompiledFile);
```

But it throws an error

> Cannot convert from int to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcSysCmdAction

Comment: What version of Access/Office?

Comment: Office 2016 32-bit , Full Access program not access runtime

Comment: I think that direct call using 603 last worked in Access 2010. Version 2007 for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Trusted Location for Access Database with code in it, if you want to user to have option to run your code in the database.

As for converting to accde from code - use the undocumented and unsupported code 603 that you found. Example usage here.

https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/make-accde-with-vba.3385399/

Don't open the database and run this command - it may be locked for exclusive access
Just run it from the Access application var:

Something like this should work:

```
string MyCompiledFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Baseet.accde";
AccApp.SysCmd 603, MyFile , MyCompiledFile
```

**EDIT - addressing conversion from int to enum**

Looks like that ability has been disabled since Access 2010

I was able to 'fool' Access using the enum from a different [Access command enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.accommand).
Will this work for you?

`AccApp.SysCmd (AcCommand.acCmdNewObjectDesignQuery, MyFile , MyCompiledFile);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I got compiler error on `603` and `MyCompiledFile` saying " Only assignment ,Call,,, can used as statements " , Then Tried to use it like `AccApp.SysCmd (603 , MyFile , MyCompiledFile);` and got another error on `603` Saying "Cannot convert from int to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcSysCmdAction"

Comment: I have question how does this logic work ? , Does this code convert the database without opening it ? what about the password ? or I will use my code to open it as usual thin execute yours to convert it ? Thanks

Comment: You didn't say anything about a password in your question. Please update with all facts and results you've seen with your attempts. Also - what version of MS-Access or Office - and is it runtime? Please edit your question with answers and your test results

Comment: I didn't mention it because it is right there in my code in the post `AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(MyFile, false, "017014A");` There .

Comment: There's an example of converting an int to an enum at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/79c26e46-8cd5-484b-8afb-de0f4b6ce54e/override-type-check?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Thanks , The formatting is very bad and can't get the code , Could you post a sample code to try ? . Deeply appreciated

Comment: Not sure that's up my alley - but looks like you need a class to override `AcSysCmdAction` and then use it in the action parameter with your 603 integer.

Comment: Is it possible for you to try fooling Access with a different enum constant? See my example in the Edited Answer

Comment: No it didn't work it throws compile error `Cannot convert from accommand to acsysCmdAction`

Comment: Out of ideas - you'll probably need to extend that class yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help , I'll wait for someone to crack it I obviously can't .